# 405 Error When trying to send test Email with Sveltekit Endpoint

Tags: sendgrid, vercel, sveltekit

I keep getting a 405 Error when trying to send emails with Sendgrid.

I am trying to send a test email through Sendgrid with SvelteKit endpoints.
My endpoint is located at `/routes/api/sendgrid/+server.js`

`+server.js:`

```
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

const msg = {
  to: 'person@domain.co', // Change to your recipient
  from: 'support@domain.co', // Change to your verified sender
  subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
  html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};

sgMail
  .send(msg)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Email sent')
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
  });
```

`Index.svelte:`

```
<script>
    async function submitForm() {
        const response = await fetch("api/sendgrid", { method: "POST" });
        // Handle response...
    }
<script>
<button on:click={submitForm} type="button">
    Share
</button>
```

My .env variables are set in Vercel as VITE_SENDGRID_API_KEY and SENDGRID_API_KEY with the same value for the API Key. (Not sure which one works yet)

What causes this issue? I know Sendgrid is the one denying the request. The domain and sender email are verified.

Comment: What is the exact error message that you're seeing? And based on the code, I'd say that it's not necessary to define `VITE_SENDGRID_API_KEY` in the file.